# how to properly push new elements to mongodb array using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

in my node app, I need to add 2 elements to an array 'roles', which belongs to collection 'users'.
I'm using native mongodb driver.
Here is my code:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Connection established to', url);

                var collection = db.collection('users');

                var roles = req.body.requestedRoles.split(',');

                roles.forEach(function(role){
                    collection.update(
                        {
                            email: req.body.userEmail
                        },
                        {
                            $push: { roles: role }
                        },
                        {upsert: true},
                        function(err, result) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('err:  ' + err);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log('update result:  ' + result);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });

                collection.update(
                    {
                        email: req.body.userEmail
                    },
                    {
                         $push: { roles: req.body.requestedRoles }
                    },
                    {upsert: true},
                    function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('err:  ' + err);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('update result:  ' + result);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        });
```

req.body.requestedRoles contains "role-1,role-2"

When this code runs, I end up with the following 3 (instead of 2) roles: 'role-1', 'role-2', 'role-1,role-2'

Obviously, I do not need that third entry.
What can I change to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `collection.update(...)` after the `roles.forEach` as well as the one inside the forEach callback. That's causing the push of `role-1,role-2`, so remove it!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the first line of code here actually correctly "splits" an array then you can just add the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
    var roles = req.body.requestedRoles.split(',');
    collection.update(
        { "email": req.body.userEmail  },
        {  "$push": { "roles": { "$each": roles } } },
        { "upsert": true },
        function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
               console.log('err:  ' + err);
            }
            else {
                console.log('update result:  ' + result);
            }
        }
    );
```

This avoids needing to control the loop with callbacks for simply adding multiple elements to an array as it can be done in a single operation.

There is also [**`$pushAll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/) which does work with "singular" array element arguments such as `[1,2,3]` but this is generally considerred "deprecated" as of MongoDB 2.4 ( quite an old version now ) in favour of using `$each`, which is the more capable alternative.

Also note that `.update()` does not return the modfied document, but just tells you what was updated or not. To return the document you want [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) in modern driver releases or [`.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findAndModify) which is the general call for that operation ( and others like it ).